# Click function on class

Tags: jquery, html, class, onclick, toggle

how can I improve my script if I want to on click on h3 show p - but I have more of these elements and they open all on click. Is it necessary to give all h3 id?

```
$('.question h3').click(function(){
$('.question p').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ay6xocLx/1/

```
 $('.question h3').click(function(){
    $(this).next('p').toggle();
 });
```

via `$.next()` we are targeting next DOM element.

Comment: @AnnieTheCross if this answer answers your question, please mark it as the answer and create a *new* question with any additional issues.  Do not change the original question.

Answer (score 2):

`p` elements are immediate next sibling of `h3` elements. you can `.next()` along with clicked elements jquery object to target relevant `p` element:

```
$('.question h3').click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.question h3').click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
<h3>One</h3>
<p>p - one</p>
<h3>Two</h3>
<p>p - two</p>
<h3>Three</h3>
<p>p - three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As `.next()` is notoriously brittle (just search SO for questions like 'why doesn't .next work'), you can wrap your h3/p inside another div, giving you better flexibility over the html layout.

```
<div class="question">
    <div class='answer'>
        <h3>One</h3>
        <p>p - one</p>
    </div>
    <div class='answer'>
        <h3>Two</h3>
        <p>p - two</p>
    </div>
    <div class='answer'>
        <h3>Three</h3>
        <hr />
        <p>p - three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then go up to the wrapper div and back down to the p

You'll see in q3, I've added `<hr>` and any solution with `.next()` or `.next("p")` will then fail.

```
$('.question h3').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".answer").find("p").toggle();
});
```

---

Another alternative to `.next()`. is `.nextAll().first()`, ie:

```
$('.question h3').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll("p").first().toggle();
});
```

which also allows for more flexibility in the html and will work with the `<hr/>` added above.